# Does Microsoft StreamInsight support for C++?

Tags: complex-event-processing, streaminsight

I have used Microsoft StreamInsight in C#. 
Does Microsoft StreamInsight also support for C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but I have seen where C++ was used in some UDOs and USDOs. I don't recommend it though because you can take a hit on the managed/unmanaged transitions.